# ShareLatex/Overleaf Snippets for environments?

Tags: sharelatex, overleaf

I want to use snippets (ones in Vim Latex-suites) in ShareLatex/Overleaf. Most of the commands in Sharelatex or Overleaf can be expanded once the key word of the command is typed, but some of them, like self-defined environments, e.g. \begin{theorem} ... \end{theorem} don't expand as well. I'm wondering if I should define my environments differently, or if there is something else I should try.

Thanks!

Comment: does this help? https://www.overleaf.com/help/288-how-can-i-define-custom-vim-macros-in-a-vimrc-file-on-overleaf

Comment: Thanks! But this is not exactly the functionality I wanted. Snippets is like, in Overleaf when you type "\sect" there will be a drop-down menu that gives you a few expansion of the key word "sect", such as "\section{}" and so on.

Comment: you mean "autocomplete".

Comment: yeah something like that. When I define a macro in sharelatex/overleaf, the macro gets auto completed, but not macros that takes arguments. This is especially frustrating for environments, whose commands tend to be long.

Comment: that's currently in development by DEV as stated in their roadmap, but not yet implemented. maybe you can get a workaround by using greasemonkey. can't help you with that, as I neither use greasemonkey or overleaf (only for compiletests, but not any much further).

Comment: Overleaf v2 (https://v2.overleaf.com) has more autcompletion options; see also https://www.overleaf.com/blog/523 for some background work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure overleaf question and should be asked on the overleaf support page.